# How to filter in one to many relationship with android room db

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a User Entity and a Record entity. I want to get a list that shows all users and their record list filtered by record's date. However, I got stuck with not being able to filter the result with conditions.

```
def room_version = "2.2.5"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey public long id;
    public String name;
}

@Entity(tableName = "record_table")
public class Record {
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "record_id")public long recordId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id") public long userId;
    public String date;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "action")
    public String action;
}

public class UserWithRecords {
    @Embedded
    protected User user;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entity = Record.class,
            entityColumn = "user_id"
    )
    protected List<Record> records;
}
```

And here's all of the query I tried:

```
//in Dao  
//first try:
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table LEFT JOIN record_table ON id = user_id WHERE date=:date")
public LiveData<List<UserWithRecords>> getDailyRecord(String date);

//second try:
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM record_table WHERE date=:date) ON id = user_id")
public LiveData<List<UserWithRecords>> getDailyRecord(String date);

//third try:
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table INNER JOIN record_table ON id = user_id WHERE date=:date")
public LiveData<List<UserWithRecords>> getDailyRecord(String date);
```

```
<User>          <Record>
 id | name     record_id | user_id | action | date
------------   ----------------------------------------
 1  | Alice         1    | 1       | walk   |2020-10-05
 2  | Ben           2    | 1       | jog    |2020-10-05
 3  | Chris         3    | 2       | bike   |2020-10-05
                    4    | 1       | walk   |2020-10-14
                    5    | 2       | jog    |2020-10-14

filtering by 2020-10-05 and get results with all queries:
id | name | record_id | action | date
----------------------------------
 1 | Alice|   1       | walk   | 2020-10-05
 1 | Alice|   2       | jog    | 2020-10-05
 1 | Alice|   4       | walk   | 2020-10-14
 2 | Ben  |   3       | bike   | 2020-10-05
 2 | Ben  |   5       | jog    | 2020-10-14
 3 | Chris|------------------------------------->3rd query don't have this row
```

how do I get something like with this? Is it possible to do it with one query?

```
id | name | record_id | action | date
-------------------------------------------
 1 | Alice|   1       | walk   | 2020-10-05
 1 | Alice|   2       | jog    | 2020-10-05
 2 | Ben  |   3       | bike   | 2020-10-05
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at how `@Relation` works. There are two stages:

1. Room executes query you've put in `@Query` to get users. As usual that query doesn't include any Joins. This query is used to get that part of data that are persisted in the main table (`User` in your case).
2. Room executes one more query. For that it looks at `@Relation` parameters and understands what table it should query next (`Record` in your case) and what should be join-condition with user's result. It's important that you have no way to intrude into this query-making process. You can't to set filter on `Record`'s fields, for example. Getting result Room transforms it in needed format (fills List of `Records`).

You have choices:

1. To turn around relation to set filters on `Records` table (but with that you'll get flat data without List).

```
public class UserWithRecords {
    @Embedded
    protected Record record;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "user_id",
            entity = User.class,
            entityColumn = "id"
    )
    protected User user;
}
```

and to change query to:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM record_table WHERE date=:date")
public LiveData<List<UserWithRecords>> getDailyRecord(String date);
```

2. Not to use `@Relation` at all, write query with Joins like that you've tried. But then you should manually transform result to needed form in code (looping result and forming List).