# WHERE clause in room database relations

Tags: java, sql, android-studio, relationship, android-room

I have a table relation in a room db which look like this

```
public class CategoryWithExpenses {

    @Embedded
    public Category category;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "category_id")
    public List<DailyExpense> dailyExpense;
}
```

My model category:

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories", indices = {@Index(value = {"name"}, unique = true)})
public class Category implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;
}
```

My DailyExpense Model looks like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "daily_expenses")
public class DailyExpense implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "amount")
    public float amount;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description", defaultValue = "")
    public String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "currency", defaultValue = "tjs")
    public String currency;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    public int category_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "addedMonth")
    public String addedMonth;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at")
    public String created_at;
}
```

And now I want to get all categories and related DailyExpenses filtering by addedMonth in DailyExpense. Can you help me?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64367150/12718414) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter in one to many relationship with android room db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361691/how-to-filter-in-one-to-many-relationship-with-android-room-db)